# Where is the default location for the magento newsletter opt in

Tags: magento-1.9

So I was exploring options to get customers subscribed into a mailing list. I noticed magento has a newsletter functionality built in and I don't plan on using this.

But just curious, where exactly does it place the opt in checkbox for the guest and registered customer? I can't seem to find it anywhere?  How does magento determine which emails to throw in newsletter_subscriber table?

Answer (score 1):

By default it is shown on the register page. And once logged in, you can see it in the my account page under /newsletter/manage/

Answer (score 1):

Magento's newsletter feature is really simple, but you can install an addon for mailchimp and it will add your customers once they suscribe to your mailchimps newsletter, which has better customization and better analitics